# UITextDocumentProxy adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset Issue

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, keyboard

I'm developing a custom keyboard for iOS 8 using Swift. I'm trying to write a function that inserts text around both sides of the cursor.

I have defined this function in my class that inherits from `UIInputViewController`

```
func nestedTag(tag: NSString) {
    let proxy = self.textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy
    proxy.insertText(tag)
    proxy.insertText(tag)
    proxy.insertText(" ")
    proxy.adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset(-1 * (1 + tag.length))
```

For example, if I call `nestedTag` with the `!!!` I'd expect to have the text field that the keyboard:

```
!!!<CURSOR>!!!<SPACE>
```

The issue is that if I call this function when focused on an empty text field with no input, I get this incorrect result.

```
!!!!!!<SPACE><CURSOR>
```

Additionally, if I call this function when focused on a populated text field, I get different incorrect behavior.

The text field before:

```
helloworld
```

The text field after:

```
hello w!!!!!! orld
```

In this example, the cursor did move 4 characters to the left, however this looked as if the call to `adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset` was called **BEFORE** the three calls to `insertText` despite that not being the case (see code).

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextDocumentProxy_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextDocumentProxy/adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset:) for both `UITextDocumentProxy` methods seem to be pretty simple and self explanatory, and I do not seem to be seeing other people online having this problem. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing incorrectly to get these peculiar results. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am struggling with it, but I have little found, so I share it

textDocumentProxy provides 6 methods

(`insert`, `move cursor`, `delete`, `afterInput`, `beforeInput`, `hasText`)

These 6 methods needs some time like async methods.
(Each methods needs different time)
ex) original sequence : `move insert move` -> result : `insert move move`

So, I tried to wait some time before calling each method.

With wrapping each methods with `semaphore` and `dispatch_async`, and `dispatch_after`,
we can wait them like sync methods.

```
inputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("happynewyear", 0);
inputQueue2 = dispatch_queue_create("happynewyear2", 0);


-(void)moveCursor:(NSInteger)num{
     dispatch_async(inputQueue2, ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        dispatch_after(delay(TIME_INTERVAL), inputQueue, ^{
            [self.textDocumentProxy adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset:num];
            NSLog(@"moveCursor : %ld",(long)num);
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        });
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    });
}

-(void)insertText:(NSString*)string{
    dispatch_async(inputQueue2, ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        dispatch_after(delay(TIME_INTERVAL), inputQueue, ^{
            [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:string];
            NSLog(@"insertText : %@",string);
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        });
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    });
}

-(void)deleteBackward:(NSInteger)num{
    dispatch_async(inputQueue2, ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        dispatch_after(delay(TIME_INTERVAL), inputQueue, ^{

            for (int i = 0; i<num; ++i) {
                [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];
            }
            NSLog(@"deleteBackward : %ld",(long)num);
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        });
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    });
}
```

the delay functions...

```
inline static dispatch_time_t delay(double delay){
    return dispatch_time(
                         DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                         delay * NSEC_PER_SEC
                         );
}
```

and I use `TIME_INTERVAL` as 0.01

This trick makes your code keep the sequence.

I am trying other methods(afterInput, beforeInput ...) like above,

If I solve it, I will be back.

Comment: sorry for using objc to swift question, but I know you can translate

Comment: This is extremely interesting, I was able to get some results with your move cursor implementation.

Comment: I think that the textDocumentProxy is working on the main thread, but each method doesn't process itself on that time. So we need give them time to process it on main thread. I wrapped my whole procedure with dispatch_async & another queue, and each time I call the method with some delay, and then the proxy works in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

swift：

```
let TIME_INTERVAL: DispatchTime = DispatchTime.init(uptimeNanoseconds: UInt64(0.01))
let inputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "input")
let inputQueue2 = DispatchQueue(label: "input2")
func deleteBackWard(num:NSInteger) -> Void {
    self.inputQueue2.async {
        let sema = DispatchSemaphore.init(value: 0)
        self.inputQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: self.TIME_INTERVAL) {
            for _ in 0...num {
                self.textDocumentProxy.deleteBackward()
            }
            sema.signal()
        }
        sema.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
    }
}


func insertTextAsync(text: String) -> Void {
    self.inputQueue2.async {
        let sema = DispatchSemaphore.init(value: 0)
        self.inputQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: self.TIME_INTERVAL) {
            self.textDocumentProxy.insertText(text)
            sema.signal()
        }
        sema.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
    }
}


func moveCursor(num:NSInteger) -> Void {
    self.inputQueue2.async {
        let sema = DispatchSemaphore.init(value: 0)
        self.inputQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: self.TIME_INTERVAL) {
            self.textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: num)
            sema.signal()
        }
        sema.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
    }
}
```

ths Jeonghan Joo

Comment: (Whatever `ths` is, stack**overflow** is neither a chat nor a *short message system*.) Please describe how your suggestion resolves the issue. (Re)Visit [How do I write a Good Answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)